# How to run scripts from Awesome Window Manager

Tags: shell-script, awesome, dmenu

I would like to run scripts with a shortcut the same way I can run apps like firefox.

I have a Dmenu script (called dmconf) that list all my configuration files, I've already make it executable and is in my bin directory which is included in my path variable.

It works when I run the script from the terminal (konsole - Zsh) but it doesn't when I run it from Awesome. This is the relevant code from my rc.lua

```
awful.key({ modkey },"n",
    function () awful.util.spawn("$HOME/bin/dmconf") end,
    {description = "list configuration files", group = "Dmenu"}),
```

In the spawn parenthesis I've tried with "$HOME/bin/dmconf", "dmconf", "bash dmconf", but none of them worked.

Comment: If it's Awesome then you shouldn't need to ask.

Comment: Have you tried with `awful.spawn.with_shell` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too late to answer your question but I hope this helps.

I too run a script for automating wifi management using `iwd` (`iwctl`) I named the script `wifi` and put it in the `bin` directory.

As for `rc.lua`, I run:

```lua
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "i", 
          function () awful.spawn("alacritty -e wifi") end,
          {description = "open wifi manager", group = "Customized launchers"}),
```

Since you use `konsole`, instead of

```
alacritty -e dmconf
```

you should put

```
konsole -e dmconf
```

Answer (score 0):

try: /bin/bash -c /home/user/bin/dmconf
or /bin/bash -c ~/bin/dmconf

```
awful.key({ modkey },"n",
function () awful.util.spawn("/bin/bash -c /home/user/bin/dmconf") end,
{description = "list configuration files", group = "Dmenu"}),
```

$HOME is a shell variable. You can load it with
home = os.getenv("HOME")

and then I'm stuck.